# Kohana "has many" issue

Tags: kohana-3, kohana-orm, kohana-3.2

I have a model named permission.

Permission has many roles
permission has many users
permission has many denied users

Below is from the permissions model:

```
protected $_has_many = array(
    'user' => array('through' => 'user_permission'),
    'permissiondeny' => array('model' => 'user', 'through' => 'user_permissiondeny','foreign_key' => 'permissiondeny_id'),
    'role' => array('through' => 'role_permission'),
);
```

The user and role relationships work as expected.  I can select the deny permission, but when I try to add a new one I get the following php error:

PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Database_Exception [ 1110 ]: Column 'permissiondeny_id' specified twice [ INSERT INTO `user_permissiondeny` (`permissiondeny_id`, `permissiondeny_id`) VALUES ('1', 1) ] ~ MODPATH/database/classes/kohana/database/mysql.php [ 194 ]

Any suggestions as to what I'm missing?

Comment: what is the code you are using to add a new one? what is the name of that ORM model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are not following the naming conventions in ORM, you need to change your `has_many` declaration:

```php
protected $_has_many = array(
  'user' => array('through' => 'user_permission'),
  'permissiondeny' => array('model' => 'user', 'through' => 'user_permissiondeny','foreign_key' => 'permissiondeny_id', 'far_key' => 'permission_id'),
  'role' => array('through' => 'role_permission'),
);
```

note the `far_key` part, you need to specify the name of the column that you'll be looking for. may it be `user_id`, `role_id`,  `permission_id`, etc

Comment: Thanks, worked like a champ!  I knew it was going to be something simple like that I was missing.